# Getting unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when running Selenium headless in Powershell

Tags: powershell, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

i am always getting the following Exception "unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.106)" by calling "GoToUrl"

```
$ChromeObtions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
$ChromeObtions.AddArgument('-headless')
$ChromeDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeObtions)
$ChromeDriver.Navigate().GoToURL($Url)
```

Any ideas what could be the problem or potential fixes?